# Java POI SS usermodel Conversion CellStyle

Tags: java, apache-poi

Im converting form HSSF to the SS model.

There is a section in our code where we check the cellstyle and so some comparisons.

In the new ss model there is not a method that gets the style name like there is in the HSSF model.

We are doing something like this:

```
   private static CellStyle findStyleByName(Workbook wb, String styleName)
{
    for ( short i = 0; i < wb.getNumCellStyles(); i++ )
    {
        CellStyle style = wb.getCellStyleAt(i);

        if ( styleName.equals(style.getUserStyleName()) )
        {
            return style;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This fails because `style.getUserStyleName()` is not valid with `CellStyle` it only is with `HSSFCellStyle`

Is there an alternative method or way I can do this using the ss usermodel?

Comment: From a quick glance, it looks like the underlying XML in .xlsx files doesn't have that feature any more, which is why POI isn't able to expose it. (If you look at the CTXf class it doesn't have any strings, and it's auto-generated from the schema). Could it be that the new file format no longer supports it?

Comment: Yeah its not supported in the SS model.....sux

Comment: I know it's not supported in the SS model, the question is if the .xlsx file format supports it! If the file format does, then the missing bit can be added, but based on my above comment I think it might not be in the file format any longer :/

Comment: U can use Workbook workBook=new XSSFWorkbook(); and use that styles i think so.